# How to move Outlook subfolder to a different parentfolder with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How do I move an Outlook subfolder (and all items in it) to a different parent folder?

Example:

Subfolder to move: Example Event 2017

EXISTING:
Outlook\Personal Folders\Audits\Example Event 2017

AFTER CODE RUNS:
Outlook\Personal Folders\Audits\Past Events\Example Event 2017

Thank you!

Comment: Why the -1? I've been googling and searching for days, it's pretty clear and definitely useful to anyone who wants to manage Outlook folders related to an Excel workbook with which they're working.

Comment: One possible reason for downvoting is your post looks like requirements rather than a programming question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As to your question see MoveTo https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865640(v=office.15).aspx. If you make it work then you can self-answer, in an answer post, and accept you own answer. If you cannot make it work then you could update the question post.

Comment: What office version are you running ?

Comment: @niton thanks for the response. i specifically ask how to do it with VBA so not cool of my down-voter. i will play around with that code to see if i can get it to work. thank you!

Comment: @0m3r i'm on Windows 10, MS2016. thanks!

Comment: @niton couldn't quite get that one to work but it pointed me in the right direction to refine my google search and found something I was able to tweak to my needs. thanks again!

Comment: Let me know if you still need help, post the code and let us know what part you're having trouble tweaking it - good luck

Comment: @0m3r i was able to tweak it to my needs and have posted the working answer. Thanks so much for responding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, this will move the subfolder "`test`" from its parent folder "`new`" to make it a subfolder of "processed". (needs reference to Outlook)

```
Sub moveSubFolderToNewFolder()

    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objFolder As Folder

    Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("new").Folders("test")
    Set objDestFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("processed")

    objFolder.MoveTo objDestFolder

    Set objDestFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```